# How to get the maximal fully related subset of a partially related set?

Tags: graph-theory, relations, np-complete

I have a finite partially related set $S$ with a relation R that is

- Irreflexive: $x\,!R\,x$ $\forall\,x\in S$
- Symmetric: $x\,R\,y\iff\,y\,R\,x\,\,\forall\,x,y\in S$
- May or may not be transitive: $x\,R\,y$ and $y\,R\,z$ does not imply $x\,R\,z\,\,\forall\,x,y,z\in S$

I want to know if there is a systematic way to get a maximal subset M of S that is fully related. By fully related I mean that $\forall\,x,y\in M$, $x\,R\,y$, by maximal I mean that $\nexists\,z\in S\,|\,z\,R\,x\,\forall\,x\in M$

Comment: By the way I assume you either want $R$ to be reflexive or adapt your definition of "fully related" such that it is possible for nonempty sets to be "fully related".

Comment: I will need to adapt my definition I think but I need $R$ to be irreflexive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is usually phrased in the language of *graphs* rather than relations. In this language, your "fully related" subsets are **cliques** in a simple graph.

Finding a **maximal** clique (that is, one that can't be extended) is easy enough -- just iterate through your set in some arbitrary order and add each element to your clique unless it *fails to* be connected to one of the elements you have already added. This can take $O(|S|^2)$ time, but that's also the time it will take you to even read a description of an arbitrary $R$, so that's to be expected.

However, if you want to find a **largest possible** clique, that is hard -- in fact, determining whether there even is a clique of a given size is [one of the classical *NP-complete* problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem).  This means that no practically feasible *general* algorithm is known, and none is expected to exist.

(Of course, it is easy to come up with *some* algorithm: Iterate through all possible subsets of $S$ and check whether each of them is a clique. The trouble is that this can become prohibitively slow if $S$ has more than a few dozen elements).

Comment: could you explain why the maximal clique algorithm that you mentioned doesn't also find the largest one?

Comment: @nomaan: Suppose you have $S=\{1,2,3\}$ with $2$ connected to $3$ and nothing else. The algorithm I describe would start by adding $1$ to the clique and would then be barred from adding $2$ and $3$ later on. It produces $\{1\}$ which is indeed maximal, but the _largest_ clique is $\{2,3\}$.

Comment: this is clear now, thanks!